# Incremental loading of a webpage upon scrolling

Tags: .net, scroll, html

I am wondering how could we create a webpage that'll keep loading itself upon user scrolling. Very good example of such page is http://mashable.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution will contain a dynamic loading mechanism (so let just take ajax) in addition to `onscroll` event henceforth below solutions would be perfect for your task:

So refer these :

1. http://www.jscroll.com/
2. http://www.webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/create-a-dynamic-scrolling-content-box-using-ajax/
3. http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html
4. http://asif18.com/4/php/window-on-scroll-load-contents-in-php-mysql-using-jquery-bootstrap/
5. http://jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/
6. **(asp ver.)** http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/